# Show or hide different divs depending on chosen option in form

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a form using  tag which will have for example 3 options. When option 1 or 2 is selected, div 1 should be visible, and if option 3 is selected, div2 should be visible. I have got script which works in IE and Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome and Safari.

This is my script:

```
<select name="selector">
    <option value="option1" onclick="document.getElementById('id_2').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none'; document.getElementById('id_1').style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';"> Option1
    </option>
    <option value="option2" onclick="document.getElementById('id_2').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none'; document.getElementById('id_1').style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';"> Option2
    </option>
    <option value="option3" onclick="document.getElementById('id_1').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none'; document.getElementById('id_2').style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';"> Option3
    </option>
</select>
<br>
<br>    
<div id="id_1" style="display: block">
    <span>Text1</span>
</div>  
<div id="id_2" style="display: none">
    <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the options click handler, instead use change handler

```js
function setDisplay(el) {
    var value = el.value;
    document.getElementById('id_1').style.display = value == 'option3' ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('id_2').style.display = value == 'option1' || value == 'option2' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<select name="selector" onchange="setDisplay(this)">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="id_1" style="display: block"><span>Text1</span></div>
<div id="id_2" style="display: none"> <span>Text2</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442225/style-display-not-working-in-chrome-safari-firefox-ie11-ok).

It is linked to the onclick event based on option element.

Use the onchange event on the select element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the div to add some classes, the task can be done more simple.

Add `options` to all divs that needs to inspect the select's value, and add speicfic class like `option1` to indicate it should be display when option1 is selected.

When the value is changed, get all watching divs and use their class to decide whether to show or not.

If you go this way, you can ensure there's no other logic that need to be added to javascript more, each time the `option`/`div` is increased, you just have to specify which divs will watch to which options, and the scripts will do the rest of works.

```js
// Use window.onload to make sure the target select is exist.
window.onload = function() {
  // Listen to select's change event.
  var select = document.getElementsByName('selector')[0];
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
      // Get the select's value.
      var value = this.value;
      // Get all related divs that will be affected by the value change.
      var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('options');
      var i, len = divs.length, show;
      for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          // If the div has the class just as selected value, show it, otherwise hide it.
          show = divs[i].classList.contains(value) ? 'block' : 'none';
          divs[i].style.display = show;
      }
  });
};
```

```html
<select name="selector">
    <option value="option1"> Option1</option>
    <option value="option2"> Option2</option>
    <option value="option3"> Option3</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div id="id_1" class="options option1 option2" style="display: block">
  <span>Text1</span>
</div>

<div id="id_2" class="options option3" style="display: none">
  <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code, but it's not working properly: regardless of chosen option, div1 is only visible...

Comment: Did the console pop out any errors? As I altered both html part and js part, is the text not show Text2 when you choose the option3?

Comment: If you say about my edited version, its because I added `window.onload` to ensure no matter you put the script before or after the `select`, it can reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript onclick event is not supposed for the `<option>` tag. What you need is onchange event binded for `<select>` tag.
This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/q08ns6f8/

```
<select name="selector" onChange="jsFunction()">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
<div id="id_1" style="display: block;"> <span>Text1</span></div>
<div id="id_2" style="display: none;"> <span>Text2</span></div>
<script>
    function jsFunction() {
        var isOption3 = $("select option:selected").val() == 'option3';
        document.getElementById('id_1').style.display = isOption3 ? 'none' : 'block';
        document.getElementById('id_2').style.display = isOption3 ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onchange` with select tag, also try `this.selectedIndex` instead of `this.checked`:

```js
var byId = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
var toggle = function(el, flag) {
  el.style.display = flag ? 'block' : 'none';
};
var changed = function(dd) {
  var i = dd.selectedIndex;
  toggle(byId('id_1'), 2 === i); //option 3
  toggle(byId('id_2'), (1 === i || 0 === i)); //option 1 or 2
};
changed(byId('dd')); // set on page load
```

```html
<select onchange="changed(this)" id='dd'>
  <option value="option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div id="id_1"><span>Text1</span></div>
<div id="id_2"><span>Text2</span></div>
```